# How to randomly pick one of known console colors for text?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, console-application

I know how to set a color for console text

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
```

Can anyone think of a way I can randomize it? It does not have to be totally random but the difference would help.

Comment: Assuming the question is "how to randomly pick one of known console colors"... if not you need to update your question. Feel free to [remove thankyou notes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

```
private static Random _random = new Random();
private static ConsoleColor GetRandomConsoleColor()
{
    var consoleColors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor));
    return (ConsoleColor)consoleColors.GetValue(_random.Next(consoleColors.Length));
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = GetRandomConsoleColor();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

A simple yet effective way to approach this is to simply pick a random value from the ConsoleColor enumeration.

Comment: +1. Note that simple "next" color would satisfy original question too: `(ConsoleColor)(((int)Console.ForegroundColor + 1) % Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Length)`

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.ForegroundColor=(ConsoleColor)r.Next(0,16);
Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)r.Next(0,16);
```

Choose one of the two for background or text color,you'll have to declare r as a random:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

or as a static above the main.

Here is an example for a simple code I wrote using the code above:

```
            while (true)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)r.Next(0,16);
            Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)r.Next(0,16);
            Console.Write(r.Next(0, 2));
        }
```

It basically prints 0s and 1s in a different text color and background color.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
`(ConsoleColor)(new Random()).Next(0,15)` returns the ConsoleColor object.

What this does is cast a random number between 0 and 15 (the amount of colors) to a ConsoleColor enum instance so you can pass it directly to ForegroundColor or BackgroundColor.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConsoleColor getRandomColor()
{
    return (ConsoleColor)(new Random().Next(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Length)
}
```

EDIT: as my commenter said, you shouldn't construct a `new Random` every time you need a new random color. Instead, you should just save the `Random` somewhere, and should use it like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
ConsoleColor getRandomColor()
{
    return (ConsoleColor)(rand.Next(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Length);
}
```

Comment: Calling this twice in a row will return the same color, as the `Random` will be initialized with the same time seed. Don't make a new random each time.

Answer (score 0):

This will select random color. Note that `_random` is `Random`'s instance.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)_random.Next(15);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();

    var query =
        typeof(ConsoleColor)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Select(fieldInfo => (ConsoleColor)fieldInfo.GetValue(null))
            .ToArray();

    Console.BackgroundColor = query.ElementAt(random.Next(query.Length));

    Console.WriteLine(Console.BackgroundColor);

    Console.Read();
}
```